# Adaptive ic_launcher foreground resizes in Android Studio but not on development device

Tags: android

I'm attempting to create a custom `ic_launcher` for the Android app currently in development.

After going through the Asset Studio process in Android Studio, the expected output is produced.
For example, when viewing `res/mipmap/ic_launcher_round`, the following has been produced. As you can see, the foreground (originally 512x512px) has been scaled according to how it was set in the Android Studio process. The background is also visible.

Desired Output

[image]

The issue is how it appears on the development device. I have absolutely no idea what is going on.

Actual Output

[image]

I'm confused as to why the development device is showing something different to Android Studio and why the development device is showing the unscaled version..

P.s. the background color and foreground icon are simply for testing purposes - this is not the actual app icon :)
I'm really shocked as to what is happening and have scoured the internet for answers but to no avail

Comment: Can you try adding in folders
res/
    mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png (48x48 pixels)
    mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png (72x72)
    mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png (96x96)
    mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png (144x144)
    mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png (192x192)

Comment: Hey, the folders already exist and contain files like so;

/mipmap-xxxhdpi

    - ic_launcher.png

    - ic_launcher_foreground.png

    - ic_launcher_round.png

Each .png file is the appropriate size for the resolution. Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: Hey, I've just double checked the file sizes of the ic_launcher_foreground.png files. It turns out that for some reason they're a lot larger than required. For example, the xxxhdpi ic_launcher_round.png is 192x192. The corresponding ic_launcher_foreground.png is 432x432. Hence the resulting icon on the device. I'm not sure why Asset Studio isn't saving the foreground files as scaled files...

Comment: So the problem is fixed?